# Snapshot a running Docker-Machine on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker

Can you take snapshots of a docker-machine with a running machine and containers to save a running state of your containers at a given point in time? I realize the main goals of Docker containers are to be small, lightweight, and disposable, but I've been looking for a solution for a while where I could snapshot a container or a VM running a heavyweight Java EE app server running a single, large monolithic app. For an app that takes several minutes to start up (I know, an eternity by todays standards) it would be great if I could snapshot it in a running state, and then restore it from snapshot to restore it in a known running state as needed.

Given that docker-machine is running on VirtualBox, is it advisable/sensible/supported to snapshot the VM and start it later? Does this impact the docker-machine/docker cli tools at all?

Comment: It was a few weeks back I asked this, and I just did a quick google of the same question and found my own, unanswered, question still here. I guess this isn't a common thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

While not snapshot, you can save the state of the Container and or create an image from a working container.

## Solution for Containers

1. Docker export  > NewName.tar

   - Example: Docker export c26aead81 > update020816.tar
2. Docker import GiveItAName

   - This will import a container as a Docker Image.
   - Example: Docker Import - lastestbuild < update020816.tar

## Solution for Images

1. Docker save -o update1.tar update

   - Saves the update Image as Update1.tar
   - Example: Docker save -o 020816.tar ubuntu:update020816

     - Saves the Ubuntu image with tag: update020816 as 020816.tar
2. Docker load < 020816.tar

   - Make sure the image doesn't already exist.
   - It will name it the same as it was exported.

Although both methods are the similar, the difference is that saving an image will keep its history, and exporting a container will squash its history.

Comment: I wonder what is a difference between "snapshot" and "state" :/